# Spring JPA postgresql- ERROR Structure of query does not match function result type

Tags: postgresql, spring-boot, hibernate, spring-data-jpa, hibernate-mapping

I have created the following postgresql function:

```
create function test(arg1 character varying, arg2 character varying)
returns SETOF "INVENTORY"
language plpgsql
as
$$   
declare i1 character varying[] = string_to_array(arg1, ',');
        i2 character varying[] = string_to_array(arg2, ',');
begin
  SELECT * FROM "INVENTORY"
        JOIN unnest(i1) t1(c) ON "COLUMN_1" = t1.c
        JOIN unnest(i2) t2(c) ON "COLUMN_2" = t2.c;
end;
$$;
```

I invoke the postgresql method from my spring boot application as follows:

```
@Query(nativeQuery = true, value = "select public.\"test\"(:arg1,:arg2)")
    List<Inventory> invokeTest(String arg1, String arg2);
```

I get the following error:

```
  ERROR 30656 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] o.h.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper   : ERROR: structure of query does not match function result type
  Detail: Number of returned columns (10) does not match expected column count (8).
  Where: PL/pgSQL function getucdinventorywithstringbuilder(character varying,character varying) line 5 at RETURN QUERY
  ERROR 30656 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] o.a.c.c.C.[.[.[/].[dispatcherServlet]    : Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [] threw exception [Request processing failed; nested exception is org.springframework.dao.InvalidDataAccessResourceUsageException: could not extract ResultSet; SQL [n/a]; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not extract ResultSet] with root cause
  org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: structure of query does not match function result type
  Detail: Number of returned columns (10) does not match expected column count (8).
  Where: PL/pgSQL function getucdinventorywithstringbuilder(character varying,character varying) line 5 at RETURN QUERY
    at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.receiveErrorResponse(QueryExecutorImpl.java:2533) ~[postgresql-42.2.12.jar:42.2.12]
    at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.processResults(QueryExecutorImpl.java:2268) ~[postgresql-42.2.12.jar:42.2.12]
    at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.execute(QueryExecutorImpl.java:313) ~[postgresql-42.2.12.jar:42.2.12]
    at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgStatement.executeInternal(PgStatement.java:448) ~[postgresql-42.2.12.jar:42.2.12]
    at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgStatement.execute(PgStatement.java:369) ~[postgresql-42.2.12.jar:42.2.12]
    at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgPreparedStatement.executeWithFlags(PgPreparedStatement.java:159) ~[postgresql-42.2.12.jar:42.2.12] ....
```

I understand that my table "INVENTORY" has 8 columns but since I am doing a join, two extra columns from the joined tables are included in my query result which mismatches my return type.

I tried changing the return type to a table with 10 columns as follows:

```
create function test(arg1 character varying, arg2 character varying)
    returns table(
          column1 character varying, ..... , column10 character varying
   )
    language plpgsql
    as
    $$   
    declare i1 character varying[] = string_to_array(arg1, ',');
            i2 character varying[] = string_to_array(arg2, ',');
    begin
      SELECT * FROM "INVENTORY"
            JOIN unnest(i1) t1(c) ON "COLUMN_1" = t1.c
            JOIN unnest(i2) t2(c) ON "COLUMN_2" = t2.c;
    end;
    $$;
```

but I get the following JPA error :

```
org.hibernate.MappingException: No Dialect mapping for JDBC type: 1111
```

How can I resolve this issue?

Comment: Error message is clear - there is no function like posted above. Are you sure you are using the same database to create function and in Spring application? Are there no errors when creating function on the database side? 

Other idea: there might also be a problem with **\"test\"** in your native query. Try removing additional characters and simply go with **public.test**

Comment: You are right! It was a case sensitivity issue which got fixed

Comment: @KamilGosciminski, I have edited my question with a new issue. Could you please help me in resolving the issue?